# $ ssh -G 2>&1 | grep -e ille­gal -e un­known > /dev/null && echo "Sys­tem clean" || echo "Sys­tem in­fec­ted"

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I found this command today on ESET webpage-
could someone help me and better describe what that command mean? my linux skills are not the best and I also try to google it, but no luck.Thank you

$ ssh -G 2>&1 | grep -e ille­gal -e un­known > /dev/null && echo "Sys­tem clean" || echo "Sys­tem in­fec­ted"

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please break your problem into a bunch of small problems. I am pretty sure each of the smaller problems has already been answered before =) Which part troubles you the most?

Comment: maybe this one should be migrated to Super User ? Well, I answered it because it's about how it works, henceforth it's bash programming.

Answer (score 2):

This uses simple bash programming to test the behavior of 'ssh -G'

The line runs the ssh command with the '-G' option (command which does not exists in ssh).

The command will either print

> 'ssh: illegal option -- G'

or

> 'ssh: unknown option -- G'

In the normal case the result is then piped to grep command that detect the expected error message (either 'unknown option' or 'illegal option') and when the grep is finished either run the system command that prints "System Clean" if return status is OK (meaning of '&&') or prints "System infected" if return status is not OK (meaning of '||').

Test if for instance with:

> ls '.' && echo "OK" || echo "KO"

and compare the result if you replace '.' with some non existing file.

Really we are trying to see if 'ssh -G' returns a genuine error message or some other behavior (because the hidden option is supported).

I can't be exactly sure of the behavior of ssh command with -G option, because I have no infected system available, but you get the idea.

Caveat: beware if you copy paste the above command from some web site, any typo (like an added space at a wrong place in grep ) is likely to lead the script to print "System Infected" while it isn't.

Comment: It should be noted that people using an OpenSSH version released after October 2014 will get a false positive with the ESET test, since there is now a legitimate `-G` switch in the SSH binary. See e.g. the [SSH man page on OpenBSD.org](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1?query=ssh&sec=1) or the [Github mirror of the actual commit adding this switch](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/957fbceb0f3166e41b76fdb54075ab3b9cc84cba).